# ZF2 Listen events in module.php init() method

Tags: php, zend-framework2, event-listener

I want to listen error events in module.php init() method instead of onBootstrap() method. As in some cases such as Invalid HTTP method passed, onBootstrap() is not even get loaded. However when I execute below code it neither through any error nor listens the event.

```
    public function init(ModuleManager $e) {
       $eventManager = $e->getEventManager();
       $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
       $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
       $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array(
            $this,
            'onDispatchError'
                ), 0);
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, array(
            $this,
            'onRenderError'
                ), 0);

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: I want to listen EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR & EVENT_RENDER_ERROR in module.php init method. Which don't work atleast by above mentioned code

Comment: Probably your application never reaches as far as `dispatch` or `render` event and because of this your listeners are never triggered.

Comment: I think thats not the case here, as if I put listers in bootstrap method for the same request they just works fine.